# Resizing only open expanders

Tags: wpf, xaml, expander, window-resize

I have 3 expanders in a window and I want to know if there is a way to have it so that if I have expander 2 and 3 open but not 1 it will only stretch those 2. It's current stretching all three equally. Also, when they are closed the content closes but the column stays the same width as if it was open.

What is the best way to get them to only stretch when expanded and go back to the small size of 10 pixels wide when collapsed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set `Triggers` on the `ColumnDefinitions` to set the `Width` to Fixed when the `Expander` is closed and set to proportional when the `Expander` is open.

Example:

```
     <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=expander1}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="20*" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ColumnDefinition.Style>
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=expander2}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="20*" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ColumnDefinition.Style>
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=expander3}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="20*" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ColumnDefinition.Style>
            </ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Expander Name="expander1" Grid.Column="0" Header="Expander1" />
        <Expander Name="expander2" Grid.Column="1" Header="Expander2" />
        <Expander Name="expander3" Grid.Column="2" Header="Expander3" />
    </Grid>
```

Result:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: This is great but when you close the expander it doesn't shrink the window back down, it only stretches the open ones more. Which is not what I want. I want to have it so when it closes it shrinks down to the size of the closed ones plus the size of the open ones before it being closed and doesn't stretch them.

Comment: Attach an event handler to the collapsed event of the expander and subtract the `((Expander)sender).ActualWidth -20` from the window width

Comment: @Overmind.900, or you could just set the window 'SizeToContent=True'